# What state and federal permits are required for stationary PAM?

Tags: equipment, monitoring, permit

I'm interested in using an array of passive acoustic recorders to collect data off just off the coast of California in on the shelf in waters no deeper than 80 meters. The recorders do require some mooring gear that will be retrieved but are not expected to interrupt marine mammals. How do I determine what type of permitting is required for passive data collection activities such as these?  Are there differences in permitting within 12 nautical miles of shore versus without? Also, is recording adjacent to or in a Sanctuary restricted?

Comment: Very important question. It might be helpful to be more specific with the main question in the title so readers know what info you're looking for

Comment: I second comment by @ASimonis. Please revise your title to be more specific to your actual question

Comment: Thanks for that tip! I will edit it!

Answer (score 7):

Minimally, you will need to identify if the location of your instruments will fall within a [National Marine Sanctuary](https://sanctuaries.noaa.gov/management/permits/welcome.html) or a [Marine Protected Area](https://wildlife.ca.gov/Conservation/Marine/MPAs). Both will require permits if you are within their boundaries. Both Sanctuaries & MPAs are very concerned with the impact on the benthic community, so consideration of the impact on benthos is important (not just impact on marine mammals).